# How can I keep an aspect ratio of UITableViewCell using Auto layout?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I'd like to keep aspect ratio of UITableViewCell using Auto layout. I want to set the width of a tableViewCell as

```
UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width - 10
```

Then, I'd like to set the height of the cell as 1.2*width.
If you know how to do it, or some references, please tell me. Thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `UITableViewDelegate` protocol function `heightForRowAtIndexPath`:

Swift:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return tableView.frame.width * 1.2
}
```

Objective C:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return tableView.frame.size.width * 1.2;
}
```